# How to use crunch to generate a 8 char uppercase alphanumeric wordlist

Tags: crunch

I've noticed 8 character passwords, with half numbers and half uppercase letters in networks around me.

Can I use `crunch` to generate such a wordlist, with passwords like `A1B2C3D4`, so I can feed it to `aircrack`. This is where I am at:

```
crunch 8 8 ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789 -o /root/Desktop/wordlist.txt
```

Comment: You likely want the -t option with a custom pattern.

Comment: How do I remove the [on hold] put by the moderator. I edited the question; Who knows crunch should understand it.

Comment: @Anaksunaman I guess I can do -t %,%,%,%, (% represents numbers and , represents uppercase letters), but I still would need several like them and then paste them together.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want with

```
crunch 8 8 -t ,%,%,%,%
```

I find the documentation on the `-t` option to be hard to understand. 
See below for the meanings of `,` and `%`. 
I worked out a few other examples. 
To do what you want, but using only `A`, `B`, `C`, `1`, `2`, and `3`, use

```
crunch 8 8 + ABC 123 + -t ,%,%,%,%
```

1. The first parameter (after *`max-len`*)
   is the list of characters to be used for `@`. 
   A `+` is a placeholder that stands for the default character set,
   which is all lower case letters.
2. The second parameter is the list of characters to be used for `,`
   (default: all upper case letters).
3. The third parameter is the list of characters to be used for `%`
   (default: all digits).
4. The fourth parameter is the list of characters to be used for `^`
   (default: all symbols, a.k.a. non-alphanumeric characters).

Trailing `+` signs can be omitted, so the above is equivalent to

```
crunch 8 8 + ABC 123   -t ,%,%,%,%
```

For another example,

```
crunch 3 3 AEIUO -t B@T
```

will generate `BAT`, `BET`, `BIT`, `BUT` and `BOT` (note the order). 
Note also that this overrides the default character set,
using `@` for upper case letters.